# Access resource from an other module

Tags: android, android-module

I am building a multi module app. On my "onboarding" module I need to access some resources of the shared module "ui", like colors or dimensions.

So in the build.gradle file of the onboarding module I have

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':platform')
    implementation project(':ui')
...
```

The problem is that the XML files in onboarding module can't access to the resources of ui module.

[image]

In the fragments in the onboarding module I also use some classes defined in platform module, so I don't think the problem is on how I import the modules

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "XML files in onboarding module can't access to the resources of ui module"? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and we will help from there.